# Unable to find Decision Making rqt plugin

Tags: ros-melodic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/decision_making/Tutorials/Runtime and wasn't able to find the plugin under the plugins dropdown in rqt. Is it something I have to install or am I not looking in the right place?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412789/unable-to-find-decision-making-rqt-plugin/) by [rsankhye97](https://answers.ros.org/users/133965/rsankhye97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the decision-making package over here,

https://github.com/cogniteam/decision_making

For installation you can use tutorials below.

http://wiki.ros.org/decision_making

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0